# How to display folder contents in jupyter notebook using os

Tags: python, jupyter

So I want to see the contents of my folder, it is a local folder and is in the same directory.

```
for i in os.listdir('/salesinfo'):
    print(i)
```

when I run this code it says it cannot find the directory
But this folder is in the same directory as the file I am writing this in, does this mean I need to change the folder location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the relative marker `./`:

```py
for i in os.listdir('./salesinfo'):
    print(i)
```